# Lost connection to "iOS Simulator" for the first time in Xcode 6.0.1

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, xcode6, ios-simulator

When I run my iOS application in the Simulator for the first time in Xcode 6.0.1, I got this error message:

> Lost connection to "iPad 2".
>
> Restore the connection to "iPad 2" and run "App Name” again, or if "App Name" is still > > running, you can attach to it by selecting Debug > Attach to Process > App Name.

[image: Screenshot for error message]

Can any one suggest how I can solve this error message? After I stop running and rebuild, everything works fine.

Comment: When I kept hitting this I found that rebooting the Mac fixed it.  The system runs out of some sort of process handle or some such.

Answer (score 3):

Follow 2 steps :

1- sudo DevToolsSecurity -enable
2- Edit Scheme -> Run -> Debug excitable , uncheck this checkbox it will be ok !

You will now be able to run on simulator. This worked for me.

Comment: THIS WORKED FOR ME THANK YOU - for the record i’m on MacOS BigSur v. 11.3 and Xcode 12.5

Comment: This worked for me too - Edit Scheme -> Run -> Debug excitable , uncheck this checkbox

Comment: Now it stuck on launching App, it didn't work for me.

Comment: I imagine it won't let you hit breakpoints if debug executable is disabled?

Answer (score 2):

Same here. I thinks that is the bug of `XCode`.

Just stop running and Run Again. This way is working fine for me.

Comment: hey I am having same issue but every time I run the app it gives me same problem so do you have any solution for this thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with iOS 8.0 and earlier, but changes in iOS 8.0 make the issue more likely to occur than in past versions.

In addition to the lost connection message, other appearances of this bug will be an ESRCH error message (POSIX domain, 3 code), an FBS* domain with code 4, or your app getting SIGKILL and dropped to debugger.  I think there may be one more message for this bug, but those are the main 4 behaviors.  Which one you gets depends on exactly what point in the launch you lost the race.

At present, the workaround is just to retry Build&Run or launch the installed app in the sim and attach to the running process with the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Reseting the simulator content and settings would solve the problem. From iOS Simulator drop down select   Reset Content and Settings, after that build and run again. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This happens less frequently in Xcode 6.2 as compared to Xcode 6 beta version.
Only **solution is to Re-run your project**. This seems to be bug.

Comment: @trojanfoe : Xcode 6.3.1 dmg is available but I have not used it.

Comment: Hmmm, you are resurrecting 7 month old questions and you class Xcode 6.3 as "upcoming".  Why are you so out-of-sync?

Comment: @trojanfoe : Xcode 6.2.3 GM seed is available. Now, we can expect Xcode 6.2.x higher version soon..

Comment: No, the current version of Xcode in beta is 6.4.  Or was that a joke?  Am I talking to some sort of time anomaly?